# If $M(r)$ for $a \leq r \leq b$ by $M(r)=\max\{\frac {r}{a}-1,1-\frac {r}{b}\}$.Then $\min \{M(r):a \leq r \leq b\}=$?

Tags: real-analysis

I faced the following problem that says:

> Let $0<a<b$. Define a function $M(r)$  for $a \leq r \leq b$ by $M(r)=\max\{\frac {r}{a}-1,1-\frac {r}{b}\}$.Then $\min \{M(r):a \leq r \leq b\}$ is which of the following:
>
> $1.0$
> $ 2.\frac {2ab}{a+b}$
> $3.\frac {b-a}{b+a}$
> $4.\frac {b+a}{b-a}$

I do not know how to progress with it.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: $\frac{b-a}{b+a}$. Draw a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I explain in details.

let$ f(x)= \dfrac{x}{a} -1$ which is green line,
 $ g(x)=1-\dfrac{x}{b} $,which orange line 
 so both lines cross X at a and b,(let f(x)=0 and g(x)=0 you will find x=a for f(x) and x=b for g(x).)

so the area $ a \leq x \leq b $,we will see the point P, which is two lines cross each other.

when x in between a and P, ,g(x)>f(x），M(x)>P, when x between P and b,  f(x)>g(x), M(x)>P.

so P is the min of M(x). when and only when f(x)=g(x), then you get $ x= \dfrac{2ab}{a+b} $ and   min{M(x)}=f(P)=g(P)=$ \dfrac {b-a}{b+a}$

Comment: Here,$P$ is the point where two lines intersect that is where $(r/a)-1=1-(r/b)$ and that means $r=2ab/(a+b)$.So $P=2ab/(a+b).$ I am little bit confused about the line $M(x)>P$ as here $P$ is a point in between $a$ and $b$ whereas $M(x)$ is a function of $x.$ Can you explain a little about it?

Comment: let see in another way: $\dfrac{x}{a}-1 > \dfrac{b-a}{b+a}$.  if$ x> \dfrac{2ab}{a+b} $ . it should be easy to proof.  since a>0, so $ \dfrac{x}{a}>\dfrac{2b}{a+b} $,then -1,you get result. now we check if$ x< \dfrac{2ab}{a+b} $,what happen to $ 1-\dfrac{x}{b}$,since b>0, $ \dfrac{x}{b}<\dfrac{2a}{a+b} $, both side -1, we get $ \dfrac{x}{b}-1<\dfrac{a-b}{a+b} $, it means 1-$ \dfrac{x}{b}>\dfrac{b-a}{a+b} $   if you still confused, you can proof when $x>\dfrac{2ab}{a+b} $,f(x)>g(x), hint: you can proof f(x)-g(x)>0. then you should understand all picture.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I think I have got it now.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\leq r \leq \dfrac{2ab}{a+b}$ show that $M(r)=1-\dfrac{r}{b}$ and for $\dfrac{2ab}{a+b}\leq r \leq b$ that $M(r)=\dfrac{r}{a}-1$.
 
As Did suggested a picture (of $\dfrac{r}{a}-1, 1-\dfrac{r}{b}$) will help. What is $\dfrac{2ab}{a+b}$?
To find $\min \{M(r):a\leq r\leq b\}$ note that $\dfrac{r}{a}-1$ is increasing and $1-\dfrac{r}{b}$ decreasing.